# Can 2 hosts with different netmask dialogue each to other?

Tags: networking, routes, ip, subnet

**Host A: 192.168.0.200/16**

- Netmask: 255.255.0.0
- Net ID: 192.168.0.0
- Host ID: 0.200
- Network Range: 192.168.0.0 .. 192.168.255.255

**Host B: 192.168.1.1/24**

- Netmask: 255.255.255.0
- Net ID: 192.168.1.0
- Host ID: 1
- Network Range: 192.168.1.0 .. 192.168.1.255

**Question A:** Can A send packets to B ?
**Question B:** Can B send packets to A ?

Please *explain me why not*, if this is the casse

Comment: No and No. Networks with different masks are physically different ("disconnected") networks. You have to spawn next device connected to both networks and set it as gateway

Comment: @Facty: Not necessarily physically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these host are physically connected to 1 switch, the obvious answer would be a->b possible, b->a not possible.

The picture is however a bit more complicated. If you test this with wireshark, the problem becomes immediately visible.

Host a A will initiate the communication. It will send-out an ARP packet "who has 192.168.1.1? Tell 192.168.0.200." So Host B will say: "hey, that's me, eh, I'm not on that network" It depends a bit on the IP stack of host B, but in general will not send an ARP reply to host A. Since host A does not get an answer to its ARP request, it will assume that the host B is unreachable.

B sees that host A is not in its subnet. Therefore, B will send the packets to the gateway, which is not mentioned here.